# What is this kind of card shuffling called?

Tags: shuffling

What is this kind of card shuffling called?

Its a grid of cards where you take 1 card at a time to create a grid of say 2 wide and 2 tall, (although it could be any number wide/tall)

ASCII Drawing;

```
[[Deck]] -> Add one card to create 4 stacks and repeat the process over & over.

[Card] [Card]
[Card] [Card]
```

As you take cards you add it to a random stack thus creating (in the above example) 4 stacks (or decks) of cards

What is this shuffle called?

Comment: I've always called it pile shuffling, but I don't know if that is its real name.

Comment: As noted by official Magic The Gathering tournament rules, this type of shuffling is, simply put: ***inadequate***.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is called random pile shuffling. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuffling#Pile_shuffle) defines pile shuffling as:

> Cards are simply dealt out into a number of piles, then the piles are stacked on top of each other.

Here is a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xgb7tEuRYYI) demonstrating pile shuffling.

**Trivia**

At a Magic: the Gathering tournament, pile shuffling by itself is not a sufficient means of randomization.

Two others popular types of shuffling are (warning, these are video links) [mash shuffling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_39ROWJbM7w) and [riffle shuffling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2EhLlSnTgL4).